# A complex-valued integral

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

I feel as if I'm probably just being stupid, but I'm working through Griffiths' book on quantum mechanics and I can't seem to evaluate the following integral:

I(k) = $\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{(ik - a)x} + e^{-(ik + a)x})dx}$.

I've managed to get up to the following point:

I(k) = $\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty}[\frac{e^{(ik - a)\beta}}{ik - a} - \frac{e^{-(ik + a)\beta}}{ik + a}]_{0}^{\beta} = \lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{(ik - a)\beta}}{ik - a} - 0 - \frac{1}{ik - a} + \frac{1}{ik + a}$,

but the solution manual goes straight to:

I(k) = $\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty}[\frac{e^{(ik - a)\beta}}{ik - a} - \frac{e^{-(ik + a)\beta}}{ik + a}]_{0}^{\beta} = -\frac{1}{ik - a} + \frac{1}{ik + a}$.

Assuming I haven't made any mistakes, the missing step seems to be the evaluation of the following limit:

$\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{(ik - a)\beta}}{ik - a}$

which presumably evaluates to 0, but I really cannot see how. I've been flicking through my old notes on complex functions and Riley/Hobson/Bence, but I still cannot see how this works. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: The integral you have written here does not converge.

Comment: Is it the $\large{\rm i}$ outside the $\large\left(\mbox{}\right)$'s ?.

Comment: You must mean to integrate over $(0,\infty)$, not over $(-\infty,\infty)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes $a>0$. Note that $|e^{r+is}|=e^r$ where $r,s\in \mathbb R$. In your case, $r=-a\beta$, so the result indeed follows.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank-you for your answer!

Comment: Glad to give you that little extra push. Sometimes you can be staring right at something and not see it--we've all done it.

Comment: @MPW I guess I'm doing having one of those moments now, because I'm looking at those limits of integration $\pm \infty$ and seeing a divergent integral, no matter whether $a > 0$. Is there a typo in the original post, or am I not seeing something?

Comment: @JasonZimba: Agreed--I was only looking at the limit he was trying to evaluate, not at the integral itself. The original integral must be $\int_0^{\infty}$ rather than $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ because the solution from the manual evaluates the antiderivative between $0$ and $\beta$. Note that the integrand is just $2e^{-ax}\cos kx$, which is damped out along the positive reals and oscillates to infinity along the negative reals.

Comment: My mistake guys. The integral should be taken from 0 to $\infty$. I'll make the edit.